# SQL: how to reference condition based on more than one table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am performing data archiving on a table. I want to insert data from eventgroupdetail_new to eventgroupdetail with condition based on data later than 2015.

At the same time, this table has foreign key referenced to Eventgroupmaster_New table. This means some data in EventGroupDetail_New are not in Eventgroupmaster_New so there will be a foreign key error.

What I want to achieve is inserting data into eventgroupdetail_new which are newer than 2015 and also present in eventgroupmaster_new,  in order to avoid the error.

Based on my script, when I run it, I got an error "multi part identifier could not be bound",

Is there any solution to this or are there better way to write my script to make it work in the way i want it?

```
INSERT INTO EventGroupDetail_New(EventGroupID,
                                EventCode,
                                CreateBy,
                                CreateDate,
                                LastChangeBy,
                                LastChangeDate)

SELECT EventGroupID,EventCode,CreateBy,CreateDate,LastChangeBy,LastChangeDate 
 FROM EventGroupDetail
WHERE (LastChangeDate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND GETDATE()) 
  AND EventGroupDetail.EventGroupID = EventGroupMaster_New.EventGroupID
```

Comment: Your `FROM` clause only contains a single table, so your where clause can only refer to _that_ table. The fact that the select is the source of a `INSERT` statement is irrelevant.

Comment: I understand that, but due to complexity, i need to satisfy the condition for EventGroupDetail.EventGroupID = EventGroupMaster_New.EventGroupID as well.

Comment: I can't think of a better way to do this, imagine if the table has plenty of data.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you need to change your `AND` to `AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM EventGroupMaster_New WHERE ventGroupDetail.EventGroupID = EventGroupMaster_New.EventGroupID`

Comment: Nick, that's what I'm looking for. It works now. Can you post your solution below so i'll mark your answer as solution? thanks